# What is the best way to handle String values that are also null in my JSON file?

Tags: scala, circe

I am currently getting decoding failures for String types where the JSON file has nulls.

```
case class User(
   updatedAt: String,
   name: String
)
```

Json looks like:

```
{
   "updated_at": null,
   "name": "John"
 }
```

In my tests are have:

```
"parse User from json file" in {
      val jsonString = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/user.json")).mkString

      val expected = User(
        null,
        "John"
      )
      parser.decode[User](jsonString) must_=== Right(expected)
    }
```

I have the following implicits:

```
implicit val customConfig: Configuration = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames
 
  implicit val userDe: Decoder[User] = deriveConfiguredDecoder[User]
  implicit val userEn: Encoder[User] = deriveConfiguredEncoder[User]
```

When I run my tests, I get this test failure:

```
[error] Actual:   Left(DecodingFailure(String, List(DownField(updated_at))))
[error] Expected: Right(User(null,John))
```

What is wrong with my setup here?

Comment: Which code produces the compile error?

Comment: @Koterpillar updated my question with my code.

Comment: @Blankman nothing there should produce an error. Un less your expected looks like `User("foo")` it should be `User(Some("foo"))` or `User(None)`

Comment: If you want `updated` to be optional, you'll have to fix those compile errors.